# Assign Array of types to spread operators

Tags: typescript

Similar to this example

```
type Arr = [true, false, "string"]

type t = Arr[0] // true
```

Id like to assign the types of a sprad operators parameters.

```
// Not correct syntax; Just thought as an example
function func(...param: [...Arr]) {}
```

So that the function could be called like this

```
func(true, false, "string")
```

Of course for this simple example you could just explicitly tell the function its parameters. Though I need this in order to be able to wrap those types each into an object as generic, without knowing them.

```
class Data<Type> {

}

class Cls<Types extends any[]> {
  constructor(...data: Data<Types[{{{at index of spread operator}}}]>)
}
```

If this is not possible, a solution based on infering the Types out of the generics would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to spread the tuple type, the spread is needed just on the parameter:

```
type Arr = [true, false, "string"]

function func(...param: Arr) { }
func(true, false, "string")
func(true, false, "stringg") // err
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=5&ssc=36&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTnKBeKBtYcCuEA0UBmAhgDYDOuUARKRgJYB2A5pQLoCwAUJ-pvQMbBaAe3oFefABQA6GWEJxCAWwBcsBAEooAbygBfbuIkZseImQrU6TSuoP8jWCmfJ5LcBo2aaA9N6gQEIA)

See [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897) for the whole picture.

To the second part of your question, to warp each tuple member in another generic type, you could use a mapped type:

```
type Promisify<T> = { 
    [P in keyof T]: Promise<T[P]>
}


function func2(...param: Promisify<Arr>) { }
// Same as 
// func2(param_0: Promise<true>, param_1: Promise<false>, param_2: Promise<"string">): void
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=4&ssc=28&pln=3&pc=33#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTnKBeKBtYcCuEA0UBmAhgDYDOuUARKRgJYB2A5pQLoCwAUJ-pvQMbBaAe3oFefABQA6GWEJxCAWwBcsBAEooAbygBfbuIkZseImQrU6TSuoP8jWCmfJ5LcBo2aaA9N6gQETk5QSCgABTghRVpSWnwQAB4AFQA+ZG0oTihstDCoBigAawgQIXwoJJZVCKiYiGTUMJYUzn0udp5+QRExfgAmaVl5JWrI6Nj4hPg4FM0dNt8oAGUlaEJSTI5Fzr4BuQVFAH0ABlHa8gTjCBS8faVDgEYz8frna9vho77nuoS3D0os1UADchLQACacIA)

Comment: But how would I wrap each tuple value into a other type as a generic?

Comment: @zzrv edited the answer, you just need to use a mapped type

Comment: Thanks alot, ill try this asap

Comment: Your promisify solution workes well for simple cases, though as demonstrated here https://tinyurl.com/[[[v6429o2]]] it doesnt cope very well with more complex types. I really need to type information in the more first (not working example). Do you have any ideas of how to make this work, or is this an issue with typescript?